# R glm(): confusing confidence intervals for binomial regression

Tags: r, glm, binomial-cdf

I have been using glm() in R to compute confidence intervals for the logit probability parameter governing a single binomial draw.

```
P <- 20 # Number of successes
D <- 1  # Number of failures
model1 <- glm(matrix(c(P,D), nrow=1) ~ 1, family="binomial") # Successes modeled as binomial draw from successes+failures
summary(model1)
confint(model1)  # Confidence interval on binomial parameter p
```

I notice that if either the number of successes or failures is zero (`P=0` or `D=0`), the confidence intervals returned are meaningless.

I then computed my own confidence intervals by numerically integrating the normalized binomial likelihood:

```
binomial_fun <- function(p) {choose(N, K)*(p^K)*(1-p)^(N-K)}  # A binomial function
logit_fun <- function(p) {log(p/(1-p))}                       # A logit function
f_upper <- function(a) {integrate(binomial_fun, 0, a )$value/integrate(binomial_fun, 0, 1 )$value - .975}
f_lower <- function(a) {integrate(binomial_fun, a, 1 )$value/integrate(binomial_fun, 0, 1 )$value - .975}
# These functions will take value zero when a corresponds to the 97.5% and 2.5% points
# of the normalized binomial likelihood given N and K.

N <- P+D     # N is the number of trials
K <- P       # K is the number of successes
uci2 <- logit_fun(uniroot( f_upper, c(0, 1) )$root) # Look for a solution in [0,1]
lci2 <- logit_fun(uniroot( f_lower, c(0, 1) )$root) # Look for a solution in [0,1]
```

This gave meaningful confidence intervals where `P=0` or `D=0`.
However, it gives different confidence intervals from `glm()` + `confint()` even when neither `P` nor `D` is zero.

```
confint(model1)
c(lci2, uci2)
```

Compared to `glm()` + `confint()`, both the lci and uci that I compute tend to be closer to zero.

How is `confint()` computing the interval?  I'm sure there is a good reason for doing it this way in terms of performance on more complicated glms, but it seems like a weird result in this simple case.

Comment: There are a number of ways to compute a confidence interval for a proportion ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)). The function `confint` calls [?confint.glm](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/confint.html), which profiles the likelihood. You might want to read this related Q on [stats.SE]: [Confidence interval around binomial estimate of 0 or 1](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/82720/7290).

Comment: This Q seems to be more about statistical theory than how R works, so it should probably be on [stats.SE], but note that you will have to frame it so as to make that clear; users there often close threads that appear to be too R-focused.

Comment: I think the question is really about what is happening behind the scenes in confint.glm.  I suppose I'm being lazy by not looking at the source, but I was hoping that somebody here might be able to answer the question easily.

Comment: I've edited the question to focus on what confint() is doing, rather than on how to select which confidence interval to interpret.